# Animated image cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I am trying to have an animated .png as a cursor on when hovering over a post - each contained in a div with the class of .post

I have achieved this before, but this time I cannot get it to work and I can't see why. On mouseover, the class does not apply itself at all and the custom cursor image does not show.

I have removed the animation CSS to keep the question short.

Any help would be great.

This is the URL - I am referring to the posts near the botom

https://mcgonagallsedinburgh.com/

PHP/HTML:

```
    <div class="latest-posts contained">    
    
        <div class="post"> post content here </div>
        <div class="post"> post content here </div>
        <div class="post"> post content here </div>


    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.latest-posts {
    display: table;
}

.latest-posts .post {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33.33%;
    position: relative;
}


.donut {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
    background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/mcgonagalls-donut-01.png');
    background-size: cover;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
        


.donut.donut-show {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(".post").mouseover(function(){
  jQuery(".donut").addClass("donut-show");
});


jQuery(".post").mouseleave(function(){
 jQuery(".donut").removeClass("donut-show");
});


var $img = jQuery(".donut");
jQuery('div').mousemove(function(e) {
    jQuery(".donut").offset({
        top: e.pageY - $img.outerHeight(),
        left: e.pageX - ($img.outerWidth()/2)
    });
});
```

Comment: Where's your `.donut` element?  Could you provide *rendered* HTML not php hieroglyphics

Comment: The .donut element is a small image I want to display on hover as defined in the CSS

Comment: I have added the URL

Comment: My point being - we can't see your code (not-)working because, with `var $img = jQuery(".donut");`, `$img.length === 0`.  So at it stands, your question is "why doesn't something that doesn't exist show" - and the answer is **"because it doesn't exist"**

Comment: There isn’t a single element with the class `donut` in that page. (Not in the initial HTML, and not in the DOM either.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the code you have in your comment. Essentially I am just trying to make this image: https://mcgonagallsedinburgh.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/mcgonagalls-donut-01.png appear when you hover over any of the posts.

I re-used code from another website I did where this worked perfectly, I cant work out what I have done incorrectly this time.

Comment: What does this give you?  Either in the code or in the console directly:  `console.log(jQuery(".donut").length)`

Comment: Anyway, your code, as provided, works fine - it's just your HTML that doesn't work.  https://jsfiddle.net/0abh2rzp/

Comment: Sorry - I didn't think this was required, I thought it operated similar to say a pseudo element. Do you perhaps know how to stop the jittery-ness of it? (you can see it applied)

Comment: Actually if i change it to apply the hover image on the whole section it works better - it's not perfect, but it will do. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you want to make it an answer I can accept it?